# What is the difference between foreman start and foreman run rails server?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, foreman

I'm new to using the foreman gem on Rails. I'm running an app on Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9.3 and Foreman 0.6. I would like to know what happens behind the scenes when I run foreman. Specifically, the difference between running `foreman run rails s` versus `foreman start` on my local terminal.

I have noticed some differences already. For e.g., a worker runs only when running `foreman start` and not when I run `foreman run rails s`. But I would like to know the specifics. Where can read more about this, or can someone explain how it works?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/

> `foreman start` is used to run your application directly from the command line.
>   If no additional parameters are passed, foreman will run one instance of each type of process defined in your Procfile.
>
> `foreman run` is used to run one-off commands using the same environment as your defined processes.

`run` is useful since your app may depend on environment variables defined in a `.env` file being loaded by foreman and which new to be present even when running a single process. 
`start` allows you to run a complex app environment which requires multiple processes to be fully functional (background job processing in addition to a web server for example).

Comment: Thank you Jonah, that pretty much cleared some doubts I had about foreman. Sorry, for the late correct answer selection, though, I was waiting for any alternative perspectives on it. :)